# Как правильно слить два массива

Tags: yii

есть два массива первый

```
 $idCountmfilmr 
  array(5) { 
     [0]=> int(5) 
     [1]=> int(8) 
     [2]=> int(9) 
     [3]=> int(17) 
     [4]=> int(18) }
```

второй

```
$idCountmfilmi
  array(26) { 
     [0]=> int(1) 
     [1]=> int(2) 
     [2]=> int(3) 
     [3]=> int(4) 
     [4]=> int(6) 
     [5]=> int(7)
    }
```

получаю я эти два массива вот так

```
if ($countr == 1) {if (is_array($idSer)) {
...
    $idCountmfilmr = array_intersect($idSer, array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id'));
} else {
    $idCountmfilmr = array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id');
        }
}
if ($countr == 0){
...
if (is_array($idSer)) {
     $idCountmfilmi = array_intersect($idSer, array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id'));
} else {
      $idCountmfilmi = array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id');
}
```

пытаюсь слить

```
$idCountmfilm=array_merge($idCountmfilmr,$idCountmfilmi);
```

так получаю

```
 array(5) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(17) [4]=> int(18) } array(26) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(6) [5]=> int(7) [6]=> int(10)}
```

пытался организовать так

```
$idCountmfilm=array();
if ($countr == 1) {if (is_array($idSer)) {
    ...
        array_push($idCountmfilm,array_intersect($idSer, array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id')));
    } else {
        array_push($idCountmfilm,array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id'));
            }
    }
    if ($countr == 0){
    ...
    if (is_array($idSer)) {
         array_push($idCountmfilm,array_intersect($idSer, array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id')));
    } else {
         array_push($idCountmfilm,array_column($idCounmfilm, 'id'));
    }
```

получаю

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(6) [5]=> int(7) [6]=> int(10)}}
```

хотелось бы получить

```
array(11) {  [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(17) [4]=> int(18) [5]=> int(2) [6]=> int(3) [7]=> int(4) [8]=> int(6) [9]=> int(7) [10]=> int(10) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
$idCountmfilmr = array(5, 8, 9, 17, 18);

$idCountmfilmi = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7); 

for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++){
     $idCountmfilmr[] = $idCountmfilmi[$i];                   
}
```

Результатом будет: `array(10) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(17) [4]=> int(18) [5]=> int(2) [6]=> int(3) [7]=> int(4) [8]=> int(6) [9]=> int(7) }`

Comment: array(5) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(17) [4]=> int(18) } array(7) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(3) [2]=> int(4) [3]=> int(6) [4]=> int(7) [5]=> int(10) [6]=> int(11)  }

Comment: Изменил ответ. Попробуйте по аналогии сделать, должно работать таким образом. Вы просто перебором массива $idCountmfilmi по индексам (не учитывая нулевой), добавляете в конец массива $idCountmfilmr значения из $idCountmfilmi. В цикле указываете $i< максимального индекса массива $idCountmfilmi.

Comment: а в чем существенная разница между перовым вариантом и этим ?

Comment: там условие было немного другое. Не учел нулевой индекс. Надо сравнивать $i с максимальным индексом массива, а я написал сначала что нужно с максимальным +1.

Comment: вот пред идущий вариант
for ($i=1; $i<count($idCountmfilmi); $i++){
          $idCountmfilmr[] = $idCountmfilmi[$i];
}
var_dump($idCountmfilmr); за исключением того что я добавил count($idCountmfilmi) вычисляя длину массива в чем разница?

Comment: Ну так должно работать.

Comment: Однако не работает

Comment: Скопируйте код из ответа (вместе с массивами) и пробуйте. Не может не работать)

Comment: все нормально заработало это я тупанул.